# Storing Email Unsubscriptions to DB

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, user-accounts

I'm working on a product that sends periodic emails to the registered customers, and I would like to implement some kind of an unsubscription mechanism from these emails.

There are about 5 types of emails and a `User` MySql table that contains all the users. New users are subscribed to all the email types by default, and can unsubscribe from each email type separately.

My question is how should I store these unsubscriptions to the DB, while keeping high performance and scalability and without over-complicating things. Here are a few options that came up, each has its own advantages and disadvantages:

1. Adding a boolean column on the `User` table for every report type with a default value of true.
2. Creating a new `Unsubscription` table with **one-to-one** relationship to the `User` table. Every email type will get a column and every user get a row.
3. Creating a new `Unsubscription` table with **many-to-one** relationship to the `User` table. Every unsubscription request will create a new row on the table.

Is there a best practice for storing unsubscription information? What are the database-design issues?

Comment: why do you need to store unsubscriptions? can't you just remove appropriate subscriptions from the user?

Comment: @Anentropic By default every user is subscribed to all email types, so I think it makes more sense to only save the unsubscriptions. Also when adding an email type there's no need to change any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 3. is the most 'normalised' in terms of db schema and means email types can be added without having to do any migrations on the db... it's also the most natural option if you already have a table for storing email types

however you will get better performance with option 1. (no `JOIN`s) at the expense of needing to do a db migration if you add a new email type

option 2. seems to have the inflexibility of 1. while still needing a separate table so would be my least favoured option

A couple of other options to consider:

- instead of several boolean fields on the model (option 1.) use a single `BitField` https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield to represent unsubscriptions... this has the advantage that you can add new email types without migrating, plus querying is just as fast. removing types you'd have to be careful though
- as mentioned above, if you have a table for `EmailType` already it makes sense to have a many-to-many relation on the `User` model. But you could use [django-denorm](http://django-denorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to automatically update a `BitField` on the model which might give the best of both worlds

Comment: The `BitField` option looks really good. I think I'll go with it. Thanks!